# Android Eclipse plugin NoSuchMethodError: com.android.ddmlib.IDevice.installRemotePackage

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, nosuchmethoderror

the problem is that i cannot download the apk to the device,

the console says:

> Exception in thread "Thread-51" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.ddmlib.IDevice.installRemotePackage(Ljava/lang/String;Z[Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
>       at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.doInstall(AndroidLaunchController.java:1181)
>       at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.installPackage(AndroidLaunchController.java:1047)
>       at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.doSyncApp(AndroidLaunchController.java:930)
>       at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.syncApp(AndroidLaunchController.java:896)
>       at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.simpleLaunch(AndroidLaunchController.java:868)
>       at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.access$4(AndroidLaunchController.java:859)
>       at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController$3.run(AndroidLaunchController.java:707)

Update: Reinstall Android SDK did not fix my problem.

Comment: This is a problem with DDMS. ddmlib is a library that implements functionality of DDMS. So my advice will be in this case to reinstall Android SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall and reinstall Eclipse Android plugin fixed my problem.